# Overflow with ellipsis ruins flex's children sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, less

I'm displaying response in rows, each of the rows is a flex container with 3 children, split by the `flex-basis` property. I've added a text to the first child in which I wanted to use an ellipsis in case it's too long. However adding the text completely ruins the view by extending the first flex child (each row has different sizes, the second and third children are not directly underneath each other). It looks like the text length has impact on how much the first child will be extended.

Here's what the code looks like (more or less):

```css
.parent-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0 10px;

    .child-1 {
        min-width: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-basis: 45%;
    }

    .child-1-text {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    .child-2 {
        min-width: 0;
        flex-basis: 35%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: center;
    }

    .child-3 {
        min-width: 0;
        flex-basis: 20%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.text-with-ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-flex">
    <div class="child-1">
        <div>
            Text <span>Additional text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-with-ellipsis">
            <span>Text to be shortened with ellipsis.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="child-1-text">
            <span>X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
        <div class="child-2-text"></div>
        <div class="child-2-text">
            <span>Some more text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-3">
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was looking through different cases related to flex and overflow but nothing seemed to work for me. I've tried wrapping the div with the ellipsis with another div, adding `min-width: 0` to it, `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` but it didn't help (but maybe I was inserting them into wrong places).
When I remove `white-space: nowrap` from the styles the children ratio is back to normal, but obviously the text isn't wrapped.
I can confirm that the wrapped text div width is dependent on the length of the text inside - the longer it is, the bigger the div gets (ignoring it's parent size). Like the `clientWidth` (or `scrollWidth` maybe) is calculated based on the text, not on the desired width.

Comment: The only solution that seams to be working right now is setting `max-width: 500px` to `.text-with-ellipsis` (400px on smaller screens using media queries) but I don't think that's the proper fix. However it does one thing I needed - the element's width does not change when the text inside is getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: You can add `max-width: 45%` to `.text-with-ellipsis`

Comment: I tried adding relative `max-width` however it doesn't do the trick - the width of the element still depends on the length of the text inside somehow (not the parent), and the flex sizes differs in each row and it still looks bad.

Comment: Is your markup correct? The `.text-with-ellipsis` is a child node of  `child-1` or not?

Comment: Yes, it's a direct child of `child-1`

Comment: So your markup provided in the question is incorrect. Your `.child-1` is just an empty element `<div class="child-1"></div>`

Comment: You are right. I've fixed it in the post. It still doesn't solve the solution - I've just rewritten the code from my app to a much simpler example for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Do this. I used a table instead of divs but you have to add the classes ".first, .second and .third" on your own. The UI is very similar and the third column auto resizes.

**THE CODE SNIPET IS BELOW**

```css
table {
  --first: 45vw;
  /*width of the first column*/
  --second: 20vw;
  /*width of the second column*/
  --third: clac(abs(100vw - var(--first) - var(--second)));
  /*third column: auto resize*/
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.first {
  width: calc(var(--first) - 16px);
  max-width: calc(var(--first) - 16px);
}

.second {
  width: calc(var(--second) - 16px);
  max-width: calc(var(--second) - 16px);
}

.third {
  width: calc(var(--third) - 16px);
  max-width: calc(var(--third) - 16px);
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='first'>Title1</th>
      <th class='second'>Title2</th>
      <th class='third'>Title3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='first'>Text Additional text</td>
      <td class='second'>Some more text</td>
      <td class='third'>Dummy text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='first'>Text to be shortened with ellipsis</td>
      <td class='second'>Nice to meet you</td>
      <td class='third'>See you soon</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not bad, but as I said that's a corporate project and I don't have the flexibility to change the flex to a table. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple syntax errors in your CSS which I have fixed below. This fixes the issue with the elements extending beyond the bounds set by `flex-basis`

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.child-1 {
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 45%;
}

.child-1-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.child-2 {
  min-width: 0;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
}

.child-3 {
  min-width: 0;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-with-ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-flex">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div>
    Text <span>Additional text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text-with-ellipsis">
    <span>Text to be shortened with ellipsis.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child-1-text">
    <span>X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
    <div class="child-2-text"></div>
    <div class="child-2-text">
      <span>Some more text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-3">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the only thing you changed is not making the styles nested. The reason I've written in this way is because we're using LESS instead of CSS. The snippet might work, but I don't actually think this is the solution

Comment: I noticed it was LESS. The output is not too far off and it fixes the issue. Maybe I don’t understand exactly what you’re looking for?

Comment: Try inserting a much much longer text inside the `.text-with-ellipsis`. `You;ll notice that with that change the first flex child is also getting wider. What I'm looking for is fot the overflowing text to be always cut with the end of the first flex child. What I currently have - the longer the text the more of it gets shown and the wider the element gets. It's like the text overflow is always calculating it's width based on some percentage of the text, rather the fit itself to it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `width` to the `.text-with-ellipsis` class. I also changed `flex-basis` with `width` and `max-width`.

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px;

  .child-1 {
    min-width: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 45%;
    max-width: 45%;
  }

  .child-1-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  .child-2 {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 35%;
    max-width: 35%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: center;
  }

  .child-3 {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

 .child-1 .text-with-ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-flex">
    <div class="child-1">
        <div>
            Text <span>Additional text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-with-ellipsis">
            <span>Text to be shortened with ellipsis.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="child-1-text">
            <span>X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
        <div class="child-2-text"></div>
        <div class="child-2-text">
            <span>Some more text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-3">
        <div>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding a longer text to the `.text-with-ellipsis` - even in the snippet the first child is getting wider if the text is much longer. Try inserting `Text to be shortened with ellipsis.` like 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have right now is setting the `width` of the `.text-with-ellipsis` to a defined size. I used media queries to help it scale up and down  for different screen sizes. So something like this:

```css
.text-with-ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
    
    @media (max-width: 1400px) {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```